# How to properly export a component from a React custom hook and a function to control it?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

What I want to do is to create a reusable and convenient way of showing an alert or a confirmation modal.

Using library modals usually require you to import a Modal component and create a state variable and pass it as a prop to the imported component to control its visibility.
What I want to do is to create a custom hook that exports a modal component with all the customization (maybe a wrapper around a Modal component from a library) and a function to toggle the visibility.
Something like below.
This is the hook code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import 'antd/dist/antd.css'
import {Modal as AntdModal} from 'antd'

const useModal = () => {
  const [on, setOn] = useState(false)
  const toggleModal = () => setOn(!on)
  const Modal = ({onOK, ...rest}) => (
    <AntdModal
      {...rest}
      visible={on}
      onOk={() => {
        onOK && onOK()
        toggleModal()
      }}
      onCancel={toggleModal}
    />
  )
  return {
    on,
    toggleModal,
    Modal,
  }
}

export default useModal
```

And this is how I use it:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import useModal from './useModal'
import {Button} from 'antd'

const App = () => {
  const {toggleModal, Modal} = useModal()

  return (
    <div>
      <Button type="primary" onClick={toggleModal}>
        Open Modal
      </Button>

      <Modal title="Simple" onOK={() => alert('Something is not OK :(')}>
        <p>Modal content...</p>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  )
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root')
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement)
```

Here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/usemodal-forked-srum7?file=/src/useModal.js) to see it in action and test it out. There are two buttons, one which shows a Modal which is normally imported from the library (here antd) and one that is from a custom hook `useModal`.

The one form the hook works except it seems something is wrong with it. The appearing transition is working but when you close the modal it suddenly disappears with no transition. It seems the component is immediately destroyed before transitioning out. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: On hook state change you reassign the Modal component therefore it unmounts, your hook actually unmounts Modal on every state change. You are kind of mixing the HOC pattern with hooks, this hook is actually should be used as a separate component instead. Even if you try to memoize the component it still depends on hooks state...

Comment: The only use case I can think of to write such a hook is if the modal rendered in a React.Portal.

Comment: @DennisVash thanks for your input. So how do I change the hook state without reassigning the Modal component? Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand it correct, you want to render a Component and also need a function which can control it (toggle it's visibility).

Though it is not possible the way you are trying to achieve with the `react hooks`, because on state change you are actually updating your `Modal` too and that is causing an unmount of the `Dialogue` from DOM.

You can use below solution to achieve the same result. The Solution uses a component with `forwardRef` and `useImperativeHandle` and will achieve a decoupled function which you can use to toggle your dialogue using button click:

NOTE: You need to upgrade to `react` and `react-dom` from `v-16.7.0-alpha` (as in your sandbox code) to latest (16.14.0) [I have not tried other intermediate versions]

Modal Component:

```
import React, {useState, forwardRef, useImperativeHandle} from 'react'
import 'antd/dist/antd.css'
import {Modal as AntdModal} from 'antd'

const Modal = forwardRef(({onOK, ...rest}, ref) => {
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    toggleModal: toggleModal
  }));

  const [on, setOn] = useState(false)
  const toggleModal = () => setOn(!on)

  return (
    <AntdModal
      {...rest}
      visible={on}
      onOk={() => {
        onOK && onOK()
        toggleModal()
      }}
      onCancel={toggleModal}
    />
  )
});

export default Modal;
```

And this is how to use it:

```
import React, {useState, useRef} from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Modal from './ModalWrapper'

import {Button, Modal as AntdModal} from 'antd'

const App = () => {
  const [on, setOn] = useState(false)
  const toggle = () => setOn(!on)

  const modalRef = useRef()
  return (
    <div>
      <Button type="warning" onClick={() => setOn(true)}>
        Normal Import
      </Button>
      <br />
      <br />
      <Button type="primary" onClick={() => modalRef.current.toggleModal()}>
        From Modal Component
      </Button>

      <AntdModal visible={on} onOk={toggle} onCancel={toggle}>
        <p>I was imported directly...</p>
        <p>I was imported directly...</p>
        <p>I was imported directly...</p>
      </AntdModal>

      <Modal
        title="Simple"
        ref={modalRef}
        onOK={() => alert('Things are now OK :)')}
      >
        <p>I was imported from Modal Component...</p>
        <p>I was imported from Modal Component...</p>
        <p>I was imported from Modal Component...</p>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  )
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root')
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement)
```

I hope it will help your use case.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer +1. Yeah that's exactly what I want to do. I'll wait a bit more for any other possible solutions (if any) and then accept the answer.